# Specify URL parameters in Rails integration test / RSpec request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing

I am trying to write request specs for a Rails app I'm building, but the documentation is sparse (or I just haven't found the right docs yet).

I have a `companies` resource with most of the usual API endpoints:

```
# Routes -------------------------------------------------------------------
#    companies GET    /companies(.:format)          companies#index
#              POST   /companies(.:format)          companies#create
#  new_company GET    /companies/new(.:format)      companies#new
# edit_company GET    /companies/:id/edit(.:format) companies#edit
#      company GET    /companies/:id(.:format)      companies#show
#              DELETE /companies/:id(.:format)      companies#destroy
#              PATCH  /companies/:id(.:format)      companies#update
```

I want my spec to indicate that if you hit these endpoints when not logged in, they redirect you to the login page. For the first three endpoints (the ones without an `:id` parameter), this is simple:

```
RSpec.describe 'Companies Endpoints', type: :request do    
  context 'with anonymous user' do
    it 'always redirects to sign-in page' do
      get '/companies'
      expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)

      post '/companies'
      expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)

      get '/companies/new'
      expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
  end
end
```

What is the syntax for the request when the endpoint contains a URL parameter (`get '/companies/:id/edit'`)? This is what I've come up with so far:

```
RSpec.describe 'Companies Endpoints', type: :request do
  let :company { FactoryGirl.create(:company) }  # NOTE: this is new

  context 'with anonymous user' do
    it 'always redirects to sign-in page' do
      ...

      get "/companies/#{company.id}/edit"        # `company` is from the factory above
      expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)

      ...
    end
  end
```

but I was wondering if this is the “right” way.

Specifically, [the request spec scenarios on relishapp.com](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-6/docs/request-specs/request-spec#specify-managing-a-widget-with-rails-integration-methods) show the use of a `params` option hash as part of a POST request, and I'm wondering if this option hash also applies to URL parameters?

```
RSpec.describe "Widget management", :type => :request do
  it "creates a Widget and redirects to the Widget's page" do
    post "/widgets", :params => { :widget => {:name => "My Widget"} }
    ...
```

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this? I have the exact problem but no way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify entire URL in you request method.
Rspec provide a shorter way of doing that which is described below

```
RSpec.describe 'Companies Endpoints', type: :request do
  let :company { FactoryGirl.create(:company) }  # NOTE: this is new

  context 'with anonymous user' do
    it 'always redirects to sign-in page' do
      ...

      get :edit, { id: company.id }        # In this hash you can send any paramter, this will end up becoming your params for the request
      expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)

      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Also instead of (post, new, index) request you mentioned above can be re-written in following way-

```
get :index
expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)

post :create
expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)

get :new
expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
```

Comment: My understanding is that a request spec should define what happens in response to an **HTTP request** (_e.g.,_ `<VERB> <ENDPOINT>`), not a **controller action**. This looks more appropriate to a controller spec?

Comment: @RyanLue Please follow this https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs
It exactly shows what is the best way to write rpecs. Cheers

Comment: As of RSpec 3.5, [controller specs are discouraged in favor of request specs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1838). Straight from the horse's mouth: “The best advice we can give for people working on rails apps is to write request specs instead of controller specs. I'd consider writing a new controller spec in 2017 to be a smell...”

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for answer that would enable me to use rails `request.query_parameters` and `request.request_parameters` in the controller and appropriately test it with an rspec `request` spec.

For this to truely work you'll need to specify the content type and length due to how rails parses the the parameters: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ParamsParser/parse_formatted_parameters

```rb
body = {example: :data}.to_json
post '/api/path?token=my-fake-token-abc',
  headers: {
    'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
    'RAW_POST_DATA' => body,
    'CONTENT_LENGTH' => body.length
  }
```